# How to customize Wordpress Dashboard Menu based on user roles?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress theme where I defined some users roles.So here I want only contributor and author can only see their own media library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/view-own-posts-media-only/ or this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-users-media/. There are probably others out there that do the same thing.

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the question resolved. That way your answerer gets that sweet reputation and it keeps the question feed tidy.